# SQL Server Pivot using LIKE instead of IN

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I was wondering if it is possible for me to pivot in a stored procedure without directly referring to the values in the IN clause.

For example, I have a pivot that looks like:

```
select * 
from DailyIncome 
pivot (avg (IncomeAmount) for IncomeDay in ([MON],[TUE],[WED],[THU],[FRI],[SAT],[SUN])) as AvgIncomePerDay
```

Is it possible to make it so it can grab the results from:

```
select * 
from DailyIncome
pivot (avg (IncomeAmount) for IncomeDay LIKE ('%MON%','%TUE%','%WED%','%THU%','%FRI%','%SAT%','%SUN%')) as AvgIncomePerDay
```

Comment: PIVOT requires a well-known column's name. Which possible values have your column names?

Comment: I have a trigger that appends numbers to duplicate values. So I may not always know the number, hence the need for a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should format the source data.

> ```
> create table tbl (name varchar(10), value int);
> insert into tbl values
> ('mon10', 10),
> ('mon11', 11),
> ('mon13', 13),
> ('tue10', 20),
> ('tue11', 21),
> ('tue12', 30);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from
> (
>     select case when name like '%mon%' then 'mon'
>                 when name like '%tue%' then 'tue'
>                 end name,
>             value
>     from   tbl
> ) src
> pivot
> (
>   avg(value) for name in ([mon], [tue]) 
> ) pv;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> mon | tue
> --: | --:
>  11 |  23
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35caae6890e260ff33aaaedcbe7e0e1d)*

Comment: what if I want to keep mon10, mon11, mon 13, etc. separate?

Comment: @AlanPear Then you must add all of them to the IN clause